# Compile fail Mysql8.0.32 on AlmaLinux8

Tags: mysql, build, compilation, open-source, almalinux

Compiling MySQL8.0.32 on AlmaLinux8 gives the following error message:

```
[ 54%] Linking CXX executable ../runtime_output_directory/build_id_test
Verifying build-id 
make[2]:*** [mysys/CMakeFiles/build_id_test.dir/build.make:116:runtime_output_directory/build_id_test] Error 1 
make[2]: *** File 'runtime_output_directory/build_id_test'　delete 
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7006: mysys/CMakeFiles/build_id_test.dir/all] Error 2 
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
```

I don't know what is causing the failure. Is there any way to know the exact cause?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was resolved by setting the environment variable `LANG=C`.

In `mysys/CMakeFiles/build_id_test.dir/build.make` at line 116

```
    cd /home/kubo/build-mysql/runtime_output_directory && /usr/bin/readelf -n ./build_id_test | grep "Build ID:" | egrep -o [0-9a-f]{40} > build_id_test_2
```

These commands tries to find `Build ID:` in the output of `readelf` command. However it fails on non-English environment. For example `ビルドID:` is printed in place of `Build ID:` on Japanese locale and `grep "Build ID:"` fails. I set `export LANG=C` in order to force `readelf` to use English.

I'm not sure whether it is your case. That's because your `make` command output is English.